# Function not returning the value

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on a javascript quiz programme , and i have return a function to check what difficulty level the user wants .  below is the code and the jsfiddle :

```
function getdifficulty(){
    var j = 0;
    var level = prompt('what level would you like 1. easy 2. intermediate 3.hard' , '')
    if(level == easy){
        j = questionseasy[0]; 

    }
    else if(level == intermediate){
        j = questionseasyenuf[0]; 
    }
    else{
        j = questionshard[0];
    }
    alert("you did it");
} 

getdifficulty();
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/utmq75hp/)

now the problem is the the alert is not showing up ? whats the problem with this short piece of code ? (In the real programme though i will not use an alert but return statement , i even tried using document.write or console.log but none worked) .

Comment: you have undefined variables `easy, intermediate & questionshard`.

Comment: If you check your console you will find a message telling you exactly what is wrong.  "easy is not defined"

Comment: I think you meant to write `if(level == "easy")` etc.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Duh ! basic debugging , ur right .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt()` returns a string. You need to make your comparisons strings by encapsulating them in double quotes (`"`).

```
function getdifficulty(){
    var level = prompt('what level would you like 1. easy 2. intermediate 3.hard' , '')
    if(level == "easy"){
        alert("easy");
    }
    else if(level == "intermediate"){
        alert("intermediate");
    }
    else{
        alert("hard");
    }
}

getdifficulty();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57pqx0nL/1/)

---

Also, in the implementation you have provided in your post, `questionseasy`, `questionseasyenuf`, and `questionshard` will not be defined. You must bring them into the scope of the function before you can start using them.

Answer (score -1):

questionseasy is undefined.  You can trace javascript as it runs in your browser console and see this.